# How to adjust first page break to some specific column using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel sheet which will have 12 columns. By default first vertical page break is till column F. I wanted to extends that first vertical page break till column L by using macro.

Below macro is setting the first vertical page break till Z column. But I want till L column only.

```
        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
        ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight,RegionIndex:=1
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

Please help me on this.

Regards,
Vaithilingam.K

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, Basically I am resetting all the pagebreaks before setting it again:

```
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff xlToRight, 1
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

Comment: After implementing the above also I am able to see page break till Z column. But i wanted to make the first vertical page break till L column. Please help me on this.

Comment: Does deleting all the columns from M to Z and running the macro do the trick?